# Inconsistency between Knockout mapping plugin retrieved viewModel objects and newed ones

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to add new objects into my knockout mapping plugin dowloaded viewmodel, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myViewModel = {};

    var Fighter = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        self.Country = ko.observable(data.Country);
        self.TopSpeed = ko.observable(data.TopSpeed);
    };

    var WarCraft = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.fighter = ko.observable(data.fighter);
    };

    var dataMappingOptions = {
        key: function (data) {
            return data.id;
        },
        create: function (options) {
            if (data.id == 1)
                return new Fighter(options.data);
            else
                if (data.id == 2)
                    return new WarCraft(options.data);
        }
    };

    $.getJSON("/Home/GetServerData", function (model) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(model, dataMappingOptions, myViewModel);

        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

    }).error(function () { alert("Oops!") }).success(function () { alert("Yeah!") });


    myViewModel.AddToData = function () {
        var newFighter = new Fighter(
                        {
                            id : 1,
                            Name: myViewModel.warCraft.fighter.Name(),
                            Country: myViewModel.warCraft.fighter.Country(),
                            TopSpeed: myViewModel.warCraft.fighter.TopSpeed() 
                        });
        var newWarCraft = new WarCraft({ id: 2, fighter: newFighter });
        myViewModel.WW2Machines.push(newWarCraft);
    }.bind(myViewModel);


</script>
```

The server-side model:

```
 DataModel model = new DataModel();
 model.warCraft = new WarCraft();
 model.warCraft.fighter = new Fighter();
 model.warCraft.fighter.Name = "Spitfire";
 model.WW2Machines = new List<WarCraft>();

 WarCraft w1 = new WarCraft();
 w1.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Spitfire" };
 model.WW2Machines.Add(w1);

 WarCraft w2 = new WarCraft();
 w2.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Hurricane" };
 model.WW2Machines.Add(w2);

 WarCraft w3 = new WarCraft();
 w3.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Tomcat" };
 model.WW2Machines.Add(w3);
```

... the method invoked by the Ajax call, which initializes and sends the data :

```
DataModel model = new DataModel();
model.warCraft = new WarCraft();
model.warCraft.fighter = new Fighter();
model.warCraft.fighter.Name = "Spitfire";
model.WW2Machines = new List<WarCraft>();

WarCraft w1 = new WarCraft();
w1.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Spitfire" };
model.WW2Machines.Add(w1);

WarCraft w2 = new WarCraft();
w2.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Hurricane" };
model.WW2Machines.Add(w2);

WarCraft w3 = new WarCraft();
w3.fighter = new Fighter() { Name = "Tomcat" };
model.WW2Machines.Add(w3);

return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

. . . and my html:

```
<div id="show" data-bind="visible: WW2Machines().length>0">
    <h2>Information Display:</h2>
    NewNumber : <span data-bind="text: WW2Machines().length"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: WW2Machines">
        <li>
            Name: <span data-bind="text: fighter.Name"></span>
            <br>&nbsp;</br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="theForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <legend WW2 Fighter Planes: >
            <fieldset>
                Name:
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <select data-bind="value: warCraft.fighter.Name, optionsCaption: 'Please Select . . '">
                    <option>Mosquito</option>
                    <option>Mustang</option>
                    <option>Messerschmidt 109</option>
                </select>
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <span data-bind="text: warCraft.fighter.Name"></span>
                <br>&nbsp;</br>

                Country:
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <select data-bind="value: warCraft.fighter.Country, optionsCaption: 'Please Select . . '">
                    <option>England</option>
                    <option>USA</option>
                    <option>Germany</option>
                </select>
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <span data-bind="text: warCraft.fighter.Country"></span>
                <br>&nbsp;</br>

                Top Speed:
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <select data-bind="value: warCraft.fighter.TopSpeed, optionsCaption: 'Please Select . . '">
                    <option>390 km/h</option>
                    <option>275 km/h</option>
                    <option>250 km/h</option>
                </select>
                <br>&nbsp;</br>
                <span data-bind="text: warCraft.fighter.TopSpeed"></span>                

                <input type="button" data-bind="click: AddToData">Add</input>

            </fieldset>

        </legend>

}
```

The problem is that my Add button is triggered and does add rows to the display area, except they're empty. In the debugger console in Firefox, I see that I can reference both the rows sent from the server, and the rows added by the Add button (containing data correctly) with one puzzling difference : 
I get to the existing rows with this syntax:

myViewModel.WW2Machines()[0].fighter.Name()

. . . and my added rows with THIS syntax :

myViewModel.WW2Machines()[3].fighter().Name()

. . . and swopping syntax between each other for respective subscripts throws an error. This may be a clue as to why my rows are being added as blank, but I have no clue why? Can anybody help please?

Comment: I'd like to know how the mapping plugin decides what tomake observable and what not to. Weren't ALL objects and constituent child objects supposed to be observable with the mapping plugin? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least some of the problem—and the explanation for the puzzling difference you're running into at the bottom—is that the rows you're adding later make `WarCraft.fighter` an observable, which the mapping plugin is not doing.

So you could exchange this:

```
var WarCraft = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.fighter = ko.observable(data.fighter);
};
```

for this

```
var WarCraft = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.fighter = data.fighter;
};
```

and you should be able to access both the mapped data and added data the same way:

```
myViewModel.WW2Machines()[0].fighter.Name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adrien, can you perhaps offer an explanation why the mapping plugin doesn't make WarCraft.fighter observable? I thought all objects and sub-properties mapped using the plugin default to observable. Thanks,

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. You should post this as a comment to the accepted answer instead.